# Can I map Windows drives to Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, mount, automount

I use dual-boot between Linux 11.10 and Windows 7 on my laptop.
There are Windows partitions:

```
C Drive - 360 GB
D Drive - 200 GB
E Drive - 80 GB
```

I installed Ubuntu in on drive `F` which is 30 GB.

The drive `E` is totally empty and I want to map this drive to Ubuntu.

Is it possible? If yes then how can I do it?

Comment: I'll remove the "ubuntu-one" tag since I can't see any relevance.

Comment: Will you append to the question please the output from `sudo fdisk -l` (list partitions), possibly also associating drive letters with device names if you can?

Comment: I guess the answer will depend on what you want to do. You probably want to have that partition as personal data only. If that is the case, do you want to make (easily) shared between Ubuntu and Windows? That could change what the format is for your partition.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "mapping" is called "mounting" in Linux-speak, and the file system used by Windows is called NTFS. There is a guide in the Ubuntu Community Wiki that helps you with every step along the way to getting your NTFS partitions mounted and ready to use:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

As per comment from @Alexandre, here is a less comprehensive but more newbie-oriented guide that even uses a GUI tool to take care of the nitty-gritty details:

http://maketecheasier.com/auto-mount-your-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/2009/04/14

Comment: Could you improve you answer by adding the essential steps to it? That guide is way more comprehensive than necessary for this question, especially if inquirer is new to Ubuntu. I believe showing how to install `ntfs-config` would be enough.

Comment: @Lakritsbollar thanks a ton for Your kind response..you got my question proper ? I want to mount my windows drive in ubuntu for use? which Way is better to achive this? May be First link or Second one which is gives GUI tool

Comment: @Lakritsbollar How can i know in GUI which is E drive from windows?

Comment: You can't, really: in general, Windows partitions will be assigned drive letters in increasing order, but it is possible to change that behavior. So you will just have to mount them all and figure out which one was your E: drive. I guess you've already solved this on your own, sorry about the delayed answer.